# Newly created Django project won't generate migrations

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a simple model and run migrations for it in a newly created Django app (2.2.7). As I'm completely new to Django, I seem to miss some important setting. I've listed the steps I've done below, including the error message at the bottom.

```
django-admin startproject myproject
cd myproject
django-admin startapp myapp
```

This is the current project structure

```
➜  myproject tree
.
├── manage.py
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── myproject
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

This is the `manage.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I add the app `myapp` to `myproject/settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myproject.apps.MyappConfig'
]
```

I add a model in `myapp/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Post):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now I want to create the migrations based on the model:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

What I get is this error:

```
➜  myproject python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 35, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    if not getattr(settings, 'ROOT_URLCONF', None):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

As far as I understand the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is supposed to be set in the `manage.py` file. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also show the `manage.py` file. Looks like something is missing there.

Comment: I've added it after the project tree overview @DavitTovmasyan

Comment: by any chance, did you exported or defined the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable manually before calling manage.py? have you tried resetting your shell (or your computer), and trying again?

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz that was it! (both your answer and this comment). I was sure I had opened a clean shell after setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE manually to debug earlier on but apparently I did not. Sorry about this and thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this was a typo in the question but, in your installed apps...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'myproject.apps.MyappConfig'
]
```

according to your project tree, should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It actually wasn't a typo but if of course makes much more sense to use the app name. I've updated the entry to `myapp.apps.MyappConfig` but the error is the same.

Comment: For anyone looking at this answer in the future, this was the solution. It turns out that I had manually set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in my shell. After starting a new shell session the solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly activate your virtual environment

Add 'myapp' in settings.py  - installed_app

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]

then execute:-
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: I've tried to use `myapp` instead, as you suggested, but the error stays the same.